# Scroll to #id + 100 pixels

Tags: jquery, html

I have a static menu on the top of browser and when someone clicks on links the menu is above the text.

I did this, but `scrollTop` does not work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function()
    {
        var sHref = this.href.split("#"); 
        $("#"+sHref[1]).scrollTop($("#"+sHref[1]).scrollTop() + 100); // <- does not work
    });
});
```

Comment: please provide a sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla - http://jsfiddle.net/cGkJH/1/

Comment: when i click on the anchor tag, i am taken to answer. Isn't it what it has to do ? How do you want it to work ?

Comment: [What he wants, is something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cGkJH/3/)

Comment: answer + 100 px from the top of page

Comment: @Vlad S - I should note that if you want to stop the default 'jump' before the animation, you need to use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: This isn't a PHP question, but I can't remove the PHP tag myself because there's still another edit in the queue.  Pleaser remove the PHP tag.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, please post that code as an answer so others will easily find it.  +1 if you do.

Comment: Vlad even if the user didn't post the solution, you should post it and accept it. Then removed the solved from the title! For more info see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to split the `href` attribute, since it already includes the `#` (which you check for in your selector).

```
$(function() {
    // Desired offset, in pixels
    var offset = 100;
    // Desired time to scroll, in milliseconds
    var scrollTime = 500;

    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
        // Need both `html` and `body` for full browser support
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr("href") ).offset().top + offset 
        }, scrollTime);

        // Prevent the jump/flash
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, to make editing easier, you could change the offset from `100` to `$('menu_element').height()`. If you ever change the menu, it will work without also having to edit the JS.